# ASP.Net Core return result from a constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In my application Controller constructor is used to create initial property objects that other methods of the controller are working with. I wanted to make sure that if for some reason constructor cannot create necessary objects and throws an exception an IActionResult will still be returned back.

However, since constructor does not have a return type it disallows me to use something like:

```
return Ok(new myAspResponse<myObject>(myObjectInstance));
```

is there a way to achieve something like this with dependency injections?

Comment: If you do nothing, asp core will send a response with status 500 (internal server error). That is in most situations the best possible answer. You could handle exceptions in a custom middleware (running before mvc in pipeline).

Comment: In general, constructors shouldn't be doing dangerous operations that would result in an exception. What operation are you performing that you're worried about an exception being thrown?

Comment: @mason In my scenario i need to create a user object from a token that being supplied, if token is incorrect this returns an exception

Comment: @AnKing And why do you need to do that in the constructor?

Comment: @AnKing That sounds like it should go in an `AuthenticationHandler`. I updated my answer with a link that should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, constructors can't return anything. But they also don't need to.

Your best bet is to make an [Exception Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#exception-filters) that will catch any unhandled exception and return it to the client in an understandable way.

A side note: If you're getting data from an external source in a constructor, you can't make it run async *because* it's in a constructor. If that's what you're doing in the controller constructor, it's going to block a thread waiting for the data. So you can think about if you can move it to an async method somehow instead (and maybe even cache it).

This doesn't apply to a controller since you don't have control over how it's created, but my usual approach when I need to get data to be able to create an object, is to:

1. Make a static factory method like `public async Task<MyClass> MyClass.Create()`
2. Declare the constructor `private` so that it can't be used outside of my `Create()` method.

That might come in handy if you find yourself having to do this in other classes.

*Update:* In your specific case of creating "a user object from a token that being supplied", that sounds like a better job for an `AuthenticationHandler`. It's designed for just that purpose. You can take a look at an example here (this compares .NET Core 1.0 with 2.0, but you can just look at the 2.0 section if that's what you're using): https://geeklearning.io/how-to-migrate-your-authentication-middleware-to-asp-net-core-2-0/

Answer (score 1):

A constructor has an implicit return type of the class itself; you cannot "return" something from it. If it throws an exception, then that will be caught by the exception handling middleware in ASP.NET Core, where you can setup a custom error page to be returned. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1